# How can I Null Check of selected list of IDs before using here?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to C# and got few queries. I am adding my one query, please suggest what change I need to make in it.

**How can I Null Check of selected list of IDs before using here?**

```
<div id="bankofferCheckbox" class="form-group" data-display-for="@string.Join(",", Model.ApplicationFormList.Where(sf => sf.HidebankofferCheckbox).Select(sf => sf.Id))">
```

Comment: Are you worried that `ApplicationFormList` might be null?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is making sure that your list is always initialized so you won't need to null check it

one way of doing this is add the initialization to the constructor:

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public SomeModel()
    {
        MyList = new List();
    }

    // You usually use private set to avoid overwriting the list. then you just use the MyList.Add(item) and MyList.Remove(item)
    public List MyList { get; private set; } 
}
```

Comment: I would avoid the `private set` also. Usually, there's no reason to allow changing the list itself even from within the model, so you better make it readonly.

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid this issue by different ways

1- initialize the list in the class constructor (as mentioned by previous answer)

2- initialize the list in the controller before filling its data

3- to check in client side (razor) use ternary operator or if statement to check if list is filled or not as following:

```
<div id="bankofferCheckbox" class="form-group" data-display-for="@(Model.ApplicationFormList != null && Model.ApplicationFormList.Count()> 0 ? string.Join(",", Model.ApplicationFormList.Where(sf => sf.HidebankofferCheckbox && sf.Id != null).Select(sf => sf.Id) : ""  )@)">
```

or use if statement

```
@if(Model.ApplicationFormList.Where(sf => sf.HidebankofferCheckbox && sf.Id != null).Any()){
    <div id="bankofferCheckbox" class="form-group" data-display-for="@string.Join(",", Model.ApplicationFormList.Where(sf => sf.HidebankofferCheckbox).Select(sf => sf.Id))">
}
```